# How can we mock the bpmn-js in jest?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, bpmn, ts-jest

I am trying to run a jest test(which renders a bpmn diagram) and I am using angular 11. Though i am getting
`TypeError: this.getDefaultLayer(...).getBBox is not a function` error. so probably i think we need to mock the bpmn-js.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow these steps (all in test file):

**Import BpmnJS**

We use these import to mock later the BpmnJs object.

```
import BpmnJs from 'bpmn-js/dist/bpmn-navigated-viewer.production.min'
```

---

**Create a mock object with BpmnJs methods**

Here you can mock any method of BpmnJs object. And we use this object to return to object instance.

```
const mockBpmn = {
  get: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
    zoom: jest.fn,
    stepZoom: jest.fn,
    add: jest.fn,
  }),
  destroy: jest.fn,
  on: jest.fn,
  importXML: jest.fn,
}
```

---

**Mock module and BpmnJS object**

Here we tell mock module and object instantiation.

```
jest.mock('bpmn-js/dist/bpmn-navigated-viewer.production.min')
BpmnJs.mockImplementation(() => mockBpmn)
```

---

Now you can use BpmnJs in your React Component (or class under test) normally.